# Distributional derivatives are locally integrable implies the distribution is also locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $T$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that there are functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x_j} = f_j, \forall j=1,\ldots,n. $

My question: Is it true that $T$ is indeed a function in $L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. there is $u\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n$) such that
$$T(\phi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u \phi ,\; \forall \phi\in C_0^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)?$$

When $n=1$, the answer is YES, and a proof can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92311/distributional-derivative-is-locally-integrable-then-the-distribution-as-well). But I could not adapt this since I am not sure how to use the absolute continuity mentioned in [one dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) in the case $n>1.$

I asked this question also [at https://math.stackexchange.com.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831042/partial-distributional-derivatives-are-in-l1-loc-so-the-distribution-is-als)

Comment: Assume that $T$ has a compact support and $f_i \in L^1$. We can then consider $T_\epsilon=\phi_\epsilon * T $ which is smooth and with compact support ($\phi_\epsilon$ is a usual mollifier). Then $D_i T_\epsilon=\phi_\epsilon * f_i \to f_i$ in $L^1$ and, by Sobolev embedding, $T_\epsilon$ converges in $L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}$. This should give the result in the simplified version and perhaps the general case, with some adjustements.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Derivatives of distributions are still local, and so is the property of being a function, so this should be the general case. (This is of course much better than my messy argument.)

Comment: Have a look at Maz'ya: Sobolev Spaces, right at the beginning, the theorem in Chapter 1.1.2, too, where it says that if the derivatives $f_j$ are $L^1$, then $T$ is in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$. From browsing the proof, it seems to me that $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ will also suffice for the derivatives. (The proof also goes by smoothing via convolution, as in Giorgio Metafune's comment.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling I still haven't seen how to remove these two extra assumptions ($T$ is compactly supported and $f_j\in L^1$ ) to get our result.

Comment: @Jinie: I originally thought we could just consider the restrictions of $T$ to $|x|<R$, but then maybe there is a problem with controlling $T_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ uniformly in $\epsilon$ at a fixed point $x_0$ (and we probably need this to bound $\|T_{\epsilon}\|_1$).

Comment: @Jinie: I think the following should work. Sketch: We only need a single point $x_0$ for which $T_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ stays bounded (on a subsequence would be enough in fact). Let's assume for convenience that $T_{\epsilon}(x_0)\in\mathbb R$ (but the argument should work in general). Since we have uniform control on $T_{\epsilon}(x)-T_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ from the $L^1$ bounds on the derivative, this can only fail if $T_{\epsilon}(x)\to\infty$ for all $x$ or $T_{\epsilon}(x)\to-\infty$ for all $x$, but I don't think such a sequence can converge in $\mathcal D'$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I wish I could understand your sketch.

Comment: @Jinie: Which part is unclear (I hope the answer isn't "every")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just to complement Bazin's answer in the case where $T$ does not have a compact support.

Consider $T_\epsilon=\rho_\epsilon *T \in C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$ which converges to $T$ as a distribution (in the weak sense) and $D_i T_\epsilon $ converges to $f_i$ in $L^1_{loc}$. Fix a ball $B_R$, $0 \leq  \psi \in C_c^\infty (B_R)$, $\psi \not \equiv 0$  and use Poincarè inequality in the following form
$$
\|u\|_{L^1(B_R)} \leq C \left ( \|\nabla u\|_{L^1(B_R)}+|\int_{B_R} u\psi| \right )
$$
to show that $T_\epsilon$ is Cauchy in $L^1(B_R)$ to conclude that $T \in L^1(B_R)$. The Poincarè inequality above is easily proved by contradiction, using the compactness of the embedding of $W^{1,1}(B_R)$ into $L^1(B_R)$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this works. I'll discuss the case $n=2$. I hope this can be generalized, but to be honest, I haven't thought that through properly.

Let $u(x,y)=\int_0^x f_1(s,y)\, ds$, $v(x,y)=\int_0^y f_2(x,t)\, dt$; note that these functions only change on a null set if a different representative of $f_j$ is chosen and in particular the distributions induced by $u,v$ are well defined. To avoid trouble later on, fix representatives once and for all.

We have $T_x=u_x$ in $\mathcal D'$. This implies that
$$
(T,\varphi) = (u,\varphi) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(\varphi(x,\cdot))\, dx \quad\quad\quad\quad (1)
$$
for some $S\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$. See Hormander I, Theorem 3.1.4'.

Now consider test functions of product form $\varphi(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$. If we fix one of the factors, say $h$, then the composed map $g \mapsto (U,gh)$ gives us a distribution on $\mathbb R$ for any $U\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^2)$. We have
$$
-(T_y,gh)=(T,gh')=(u,gh')+S(h')\int g =-(v_y, gh)=(v,gh') .
$$
The third and fifth expressions, thought of as one-dimensional distributions acting on $g$, are functions. Hence
$$
S(h')=\int (v(x,y)-u(x,y))h'(y)\, dy
$$
for almost every $x$. Here the exceptional null set may depend on $h'$. However, since a countable set of $h$'s suffices to determine $S$ on the codimension $1$ subspace of derivatives $h'$, it is in fact true that $v(x,y)-u(x,y)=w(y)+c(x)$ for almost every $x$. See [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154595/is-the-space-of-test-functions-separable)
Hence $S'=-w$ and thus also $S$ itself are functions. Now we can go back to (1) to confirm that $T$ is a function also.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is a distribution on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\nabla T$ belongs to $L^1_{\text{loc}}$, the isoperimetric inequality implies that
$$
T\in L^\frac{n}{n-1}_{\text{loc}}.
\tag{1}
$$
To prove this, you need only to multiply $T$ by a smooth compactly supported function $\chi$, so that $u=\chi T$ is a distribution with compact support and with gradient in $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$. You may then define
$
v_\epsilon=u\ast \rho_\epsilon
$
where $\rho_\epsilon$ is a standard mollifier and you get that $v_\epsilon$
is smooth and compactly supported so that
$$
c_n\Vert v_\epsilon\Vert_{L^\frac{n}{n-1}(\mathbb R^n)}\le 
\Vert \nabla v_\epsilon\Vert_{L^1(\mathbb R^n)},
$$
which is essentially enough to get that $u$ belongs to $L^\frac{n}{n-1}(\mathbb R^n)$ and thus (1).

Comment: Why is $\nabla u = \chi \nabla T + (\nabla\chi) T\in L^1$ ?

Comment: @Bazin The same concern as Christian.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to get the same conclusion, maybe a tiny bit more elementary than the answers above. First, the question can be localized replacing $T$ with $T\theta$ for some arbitrary bump function $\theta$ : I assume now that $T$ is compactly supported with $\nabla T=F\in L^1(\mathbf{R}^n)$.

For a any smooth function $\varphi$ and $x,h\in\mathbf{R}^n$ there holds
$$ \tau_h \varphi - \varphi = \int_0^1 (\tau_{sh}\nabla \varphi,h)\, \mathrm{d}s$$
where $( \cdot,\cdot)$ is the euclidean inner-product and $\tau_h \varphi(x) = \varphi(x+h)$. A direct bracket/duality computation gives in our case
$$\tau_h T - T = \int_0^1 ( \tau_{sh} F,h) \,\mathrm{d} s:= G_h,$$
where one checks that $G_h$ is a well-defined $L^1(\mathbf{R}^d)$ element. Up to now, this is more or less equivalent to what have done Christian Remling above. Now, since $T$ has compact support, say $K$, we fix a test function $\psi$ supported in $K$ and we pick $h$ large enough so that the support of $\tau_h T$ does not meet $K$ : we have $\langle T,\psi \rangle = \langle T-\tau_h T,\psi\rangle = -\langle G_h,\psi\rangle$ and the conclusion follows.